# If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is a continuous function, then $f(\mathbb{R})$ has empty interior.

Tags: general-topology

I am supposed to use connectedness here.

Clearly, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is connected. But what now?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, what are the connected subspaces of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Q}$, and what is the interior of such a subspace?

Comment: $I\times \{p\}$, where $I$ is a interval? Can I call it a basic connected subspace?

Comment: No, that is all. Every continuous function from real to real cross rationals has empty interior.

Comment: You could argue that every open set in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb Q$ has at least two values in the $\mathbb Q$ part.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$, $h:R\rightarrow Q$ is continuous. Let $i:Q\rightarrow R$ the canonical embedding, $i\circ h$ is continue. This implies its image is an interval since the connected subsets of $R$ are the intervals. But $i(h(R))$ is contained in $i(Q)$ thus is a constant since the only intervals contained in $i(Q)$ are the singletons.

Comment: Oh, thanks. The part "$f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$" gave me the hint.